# I am looking for a way in R to drop a column depending on the position of a certain condition being met

Tags: r, matrix, statistics

I can best explain this via a random example

```
A<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),nrow=3,ncol=3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    1    1    2
[3,]    1    1    2
```

I have another random set lets say

```
B<-(2,4,5)
```

Is there a way to drop the vectors that correspond to the position of the odd numbers in B? so I want the third column to be dropped because the third entry in B is odd.

edit

sorry for the late edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
A[,-which(B%%2==1)]
```

which gives

```
> A[,-which(B%%2==1)]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `IsOdd` from `DescTools`

```
library(DescTools)
A[,!IsOdd(B)]
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    1    1
```